# Google App Script -The script completed but did not return anything - row inserted only if the website is reloaded

Tags: google-apps-script, woocommerce, webhooks

To send the received orders to google sheets, I am using the below script which

a. returns the error "The script completed but did not return anything" in woocommerce log and 
b. appends a new row in Google Sheets for the received order data to Google sheets only when I manually reload the website (https://restaurants.fasteco.am/).

Could you please advise how to fix the issue?
Disabling the caching plugins helps but the plufgin is much needed. Is there a way to solve the issue in a way other than disabling the caching plugin (Siteground optimizer).
Thanks in advance for checking!

```
//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a GET request
function doGet( e ) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput( "request received" );
}

//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a POST request
function doPost( e ) {
    var myData          = JSON.parse( [ e.postData.getDataAsString() ] );
    var order_number    = myData.number;
    var order_created   = myData.date_created;
    var billing_company = myData.billing.company;
    var notes           = myData.customer_note;
    var timestamp       = new Date();
    var sheet           = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var values          = [];

    for ( var i = 0; i < myData.line_items.length; i++ ) {
        var product_sku  = myData.line_items[ i ].sku;
        var product_name = myData.line_items[ i ].name;
        var product_qty  = myData.line_items[ i ].quantity;

        values.push( [ product_name, billing_company, product_qty, notes, order_created, order_number, product_sku ] );
    }

    // Put values using "setValues".
    sheet.getRange( sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[ 0 ].length ).setValues( values );

    // Refresh basic filter.
    var filter = sheet.getFilter();

    if ( filter ) {
        var range = filter.getRange();

        for ( var i = range.getColumn(), maxCol = range.getLastColumn(); i <= maxCol; i++ ) {
            var filterCriteria = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria( i )

            if ( filterCriteria ) {
                filter.setColumnFilterCriteria( i, filterCriteria );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would image that `resturants fastco` has to be refreshed to get the data from Google sheets.  It doesn't know you updated the sheet.

Comment: Hi, the issue is that it is sheets that needs to be updated upon receiving a new order from woocommerce, based on the webhook and the script google apps script in the sheets.